# Interrumpir ciclo while al pulsar una tecla

Tags: python, python-2.7, bucles

¿Cómo hago para interrumpir este bucle?

```
import time
t=0
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print (t)
    t=t+1
```

Necesito que se ejecute hasta que presione una tecla determinada.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar el módulo **[keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)**<sup>1</sup> para detectar si una tecla en particular ha sido presionada, y `break` para detener el ciclo.

En resumen, supongamos que utlizaremos la tecla <kbd>p</kbd> para **p**arar, el código podría ser algo como:

```
import time
import keyboard
t=0
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print (t)
    t=t+1
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        print('se presionó [p]arar!')
        break
```

<sup>1</sup> Si no está instalado el módulo, instalalo, con `pip install keyboard`.

Comment: Funciona con Python 2.7?

Comment: No puedo cargar el módulo keyboard...

Comment: En Sublime Text me dice ImportError: No module named keyboard

Comment: Tampoco puedo hacerlo desde cmd, me baje el https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ y me da error al hacer pip install setup.py

Comment: Ya está, gracias!!

Comment: Perfecto, lo dejo en tus manos, soy novato en esto y puedo errarle.

Comment: Te la voy a complicar, esto tiene que correr en una Raspberry Pi con Jessie. No logro que funcione. Alguna idea?

Comment: Tu pregunta original no mencionaba nada de eso, te recomiendo leer [ask]. Considero que bajo los parámetros de tu pregunta original, mi respuesta es aceptable.

Comment: Totalmente aceptable!!! estoy investigando, aprendiendo, voy de a poco y tu ayuda estuvo muy bien. Disculpá si cometí algún error.

Comment: No hay problema. En realidad, si tienes una nueva pregunta, es totalmente normal y aceptable que la plantees dentro del sitio, como una nueva pregunta. De otra manera, estaríamos constantemente invalidando el esfuerzo de quienes responden, pues es habitual que se olvide algún _pequeño detalle_ que simplemente cambia toda la respuesta. Esto ocurre también en la vida real, con cambios de requerimientos, que yo suelo manejar de la misma manera con los clientes que pagan. :) Un saludo.

Comment: Me funciona correctamente en Sublime, en Windows, pero no en Rasp con Jessie y Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Sin salirse de la biblioteca estándar de Python podemos recurrir a [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) (disponible en Linux) para capturar pulsaciones de teclas de forma asíncrona. Una implementación básica podría ser:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import curses


def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.nodelay(True)
    try:
        return stdscr.getkey()
    except:
        return None

def key_pressed(key):
    inp_key = curses.wrapper(main)

    while inp_key is not None:
        if key == inp_key:
            return True
        inp_key = curses.wrapper(main)
    return False
```

Con esto (podemos guardarlo en otro módulo e importarlo si queremos), solo tenemos que hacer en el ciclo a detener:

```
import time


t = 0
while not key_pressed("q"):
    print(t)
    time.sleep(1)
    t = t + 1
```

> El script debe ejecutarse en una terminal del sistema, no hay garantía de que funcione si se ejecuta en la consola integrada de un IDE.

---

> Funcionará con cualquier tecla que genere un carácter dentro del rango ASCII,  por tanto representados por un solo byte. En el caso de caracteres no ASCII, la pulsación de la tecla genera una cadena multibytes y `getch`/`getkey` nos retornará cada byte por separado, por lo que no podremos usarlo con teclas como `ñ`. Algo similar pasa con teclas como las flechas en terminales VT100-like, las cuales generan una secuencia de tres bytes. Esto se puede solucionar pero se complica bastante el código además de la portabilidad.

Comment: Cómo comenté en la otra respuesta, esto tiene que correr en una Raspberry Py con Jessie. Funcionará?

Comment: No hay modo, no hace nada. Qué puedo estar haciendo mal? lo ejecuto en una Raspberry Pi con Jessie y Python 2.7.

Comment: @danielfelix he editado la pregunta, por un malentendido culapa mia estaba capturando las teclas de forma bloqueante. Ahora debería funcionar sin problemas. cualquier cosa comenta.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si el script se ejecuta en ***Windows***, puedes utilizar el módulo integrado en python [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/library/msvcrt.html) y obtendrás una manera fácil de controlar esto.
Tú código quedaría así:

```
import time
import msvcrt   # Consola E/S, solo para Windows

t=0
while True:
    
    if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getwch()=='q':
        break

    time.sleep(1)
    print (t)
    t=t+1
```

Pulsando la tecla "q" se sale del bucle.