# Salir de dos bucles al presionar una tecla

Tags: python-2.7, bucles, consola, teclado

tengo este código:

```
def duerme():
    t=0 
    for t in range(0,10):       
        time.sleep(1)
        print(t)     
        t=t+1


for i in range (0,10):
        print "i=", (i)
        i+=1
        duerme()
```

Como me mostraron en este post: [Interrumpir ciclo while al pulsar una tecla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/261659/interrumpir-ciclo-while-al-pulsar-una-tecla/261671?noredirect=1#comment484767_261671), logro salir de un solo bucle usando el método de FJSevilla, necesito salir de ambos.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de esta manera, es válida?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import curses
import time
import sys

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.nodelay(True)
    try:
        return stdscr.getkey()
    except:
        return None

def key_pressed(key):
    inp_key = curses.wrapper(main)

    while inp_key is not None:
        if key == inp_key:
            return True
        inp_key = curses.wrapper(main)
    return False

def duerme():
    t=0 
    while not key_pressed("q"):     
        time.sleep(1)
        print(t)     
        t=t+1
    return "fin"    

for i in range (0,10):

    sale= duerme()
    print (sale)

    if sale!=("fin"):
           print "i=", (i)
           i+=1
           duerme()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: La idea general (que la función `duerme()` devuelva algo para indicar que ha sido interrumpida) me parece buena. Luego hay detalles varios en el código que se podrían mejorar. Por decir alguno, estás llamando a `duerme()` dos veces en cada iteración del bucle. Y estás haciendo un `i+=1` innecesario (pues el `for` ya iterará de todas formas por los valores del rango). Es más, yo cambiaría el `if...else` final por un simple `if sale=="fin": break`

Comment: Gracias, lo estudiaré.